# Floating point exception (Core dumped ) openmpi and centos 7 i686

Tags: c, mpi, centos7, openmpi

I am a beginner in MPI programming, we are trying to run a program over a cluster of three machines using Centos 7 i686.
After installing OpenMPI packages which are provided with the installation media  of Centos 7 i686 :

```
openmpi-1.10.0-10.el7.i686.rpm 
openmpi-devel-1.10.0-10.el7.i686.rpm
```

We added the `openmpi` module to `Environment-modules`, 
added also environment variables to recognize the commands

then when trying to test it on a single machine, using this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int rank, size, len;
    char version[MPI_MAX_LIBRARY_VERSION_STRING];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Get_library_version(version, &len);
    printf("Hello, world, I am %d of %d, (%s, %d)\n", 
           rank, size, version, len);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

mpicc compiles well without problem if using this command:

```
mpicc mpitest.c -o mpitest
```

but when trying to run the executable with

```
mpirun -np 2 ./mpitest
```

I get this error:

```
[localhost:09496] *** Process received signal ***
[localhost:09496] Signal: Floating point exception (8)
[localhost:09496] Signal code: Integer divide-by-zero (1)
[localhost:09496] Failing at address: 0xb7617df7
[localhost:09496] [ 0] [0xb77a940c]
[localhost:09496] [ 1] /lib/libhwloc.so.5(+0x21df7)[0xb7617df7]
[localhost:09496] [ 2] /lib/libhwloc.so.5(+0x23093)[0xb7619093]
[localhost:09496] [ 3] /lib/libhwloc.so.5(+0x23214)[0xb7619214]
[localhost:09496] [ 4] /lib/libhwloc.so.5(hwloc_topology_load+0x165)[0xb75ff2a5]
[localhost:09496] [ 5] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.13(opal_hwloc_base_get_topology+0xda)[0xb76fa41a]
[localhost:09496] [ 6] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_ess_hnp.so(+0x3c9a)[0xb7683c9a]
[localhost:09496] [ 7] /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.12(orte_init+0x187)[0xb773fa37]
[localhost:09496] [ 8] mpirun[0x804b542]
[localhost:09496] [ 9] mpirun[0x804a74b]
[localhost:09496] [10] /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb7438943]
[localhost:09496] [11] mpirun[0x804a651]
[localhost:09496] *** End of error message ***
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

If anyone has faced the same problem, please I need some help figuring out what's wrong!

I also tried compiling the helloWorld.c which comes with the OpenMPI files and got the same error, so I believe that the problem isn't in the source code.

Comment: This looks like a bug in OpenMPI or your compiler. It has been [observed before](http://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/mOIkcOU8/ompi-users-signal-code-integer-divide-by-zero), but that seemed to be an old version. You could maybe try to compile a more recent `hwloc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zulan ,after reading about hwloc I found that using it will require changing the source code of my programs which is not allowed in my case. Does this bug exists in all the openmpi releases or using an earlier version can fix the problem ?

Comment: I don't understand why / how `hwloc` would have anything to do with the source code of your program. There doesn't seem much information about this issue, if it is indeed a bug in OpenMPI, it might be best to report it to OpenMPI directly.

Comment: Okey, i have to say, I didn't really understand how to use hwloc, I'll documente about it, and I'll report the bug ... many thanks @Zulan